# Greatest $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are Hamming numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

As we know, Hamming numbers are numbers with all prime factors $\leq 5$.
How can we determine the greatest $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are Hamming numbers? If there is such an $n$....

Comment: $80,81$.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence [$A085152$ in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085152) gives all the numbers $n $ such that $n $ and $n+1$ have prime factors $\leq 5$, that is, are Hamming numbers.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did help for this particular case. Going from Hamming numbers to other p-smooth numbers might be covered by Stromers theorem, I suspect.